# generic Type of multiple classes in java

Tags: java, generics, type-bounds

How can achieve to boud a generic Type of a class to multiple calsses?
A example is subclasses of Number and Boolean.

Comment: How do you expect to use this generic parameter? To clarify your question please write a code example (probably using some non-existing language construct you want to have).

Comment: Read about interfaces and polymorphism, and by the way the JDK has the Object class which is the super class of all other classes that are there in the JDK or that you create yourself. So the Object class can act as a generic type when receiving method parameters or when creating a collection of different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, one of the options is to create additional enum-like class with limited number of instances:

```
public final class ValueType<T> {
    public static final ValueType<Boolean> BOOLEAN = new ValueType<>(Boolean.class);
    public static final ValueType<Integer> INTEGER = new ValueType<>(Integer.class);

    private final Class<T> clazz;

    private ValueType(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return clazz;
    }
}
```

Now your class can be declared this way:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    public MyClass(ValueType<T> type) {
        Class<T> clazz = type.getType();
    }
}
```

So you can instantiate it like

```
MyClass<Boolean> c = new MyClass<>(ValueType.BOOLEAN);
```

Or

```
MyClass<Integer> c = new MyClass<>(ValueType.INTEGER);
```

But you have no other options, because you have no other `ValueType` objects.